# Affine transformation matrix offset

Tags: javascript, graphics, matrix, html5-canvas, affinetransform

This has been killing me the last few days. Not even kidding, but I've been really stressing over this trying to solve it.

I am currently trying to use affine transformation matrices to create an isometric projection in HTML5. 
I receive a tile which is a square that is rotated 45 degrees (essentially a square diamond on a square canvas). I then scale one of the axis' depending on if the there is a delta in the x or y direction.
I then skew the axis by a factor to fit. Then, I negate the initial rotation by rotating it back by -45 degrees.

Currently, my affine matrix is:

```
      // note: the difference in z is about 10 in this example,
      //       so, xDiff is usually 40
      var xDiff  = 4 * (center.z   - map[x+1][y].land.z);
      var yDiff  = 4 * (center.z   - map[x][y+1].land.z);

      var matrix = multiplyAll(
        // Rotation
        [COS45,  SIN45,
         -SIN45, COS45],

        // Scale in each respective axis
        [(44+yDiff)/44, 0,
         0, (44+xDiff)/44],

        // Skew each axis
        [1,  -yDiff/(44+yDiff),
         -xDiff/(44+xDiff), 1],

        // Negate the rotation
        [NCOS45, NSIN45,
        -NSIN45, NCOS45]
      );
```

Then I draw it using:

```
      // the map has its own x & y values which directions are determined by the red x & y arrows in the picture
      // pX & pY are the point relative to the canvas origin
      var pX = x * 22 - y * 22 + 22;
      var pY = y * 22 + x * 22 - 22 - (center.z * 4);
      context.setTransform(matrix[0], matrix[1],
                           matrix[2], matrix[3],

                           300, 100);

      //m_Context.drawImage(image, pX, pY);
      drawDiamond(pX, pY, true); // draws a 44x44 diamond
```

[image: Projection test]

[image: Transformed plane]

As you can see, the transformed matrices are being drawn with respect to the transformed x-axis (I think the "new" x-axis has a slope of yDiff/44). I'm not sure how to draw the shapes so that the transformed result will be in the correct position. Using `pY = x * 22 - (yDiff/10);` seems to get the point closer, but I pretty much guessed it by plugging in random numbers.

**tl;dr:**

- I performed a transformation
- I have a coordinate where a tile should be (if it wasn't transformed)
- How to I calculate the offset required so that a transformed tile's coordinate is the same as where it should be if it was not transformed?

PS: The weird diamonds on the bottom can be ignored for now since they can [correctly be created](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/basic-isometric-projection-in-javascript/48571#48571) ONCE I find out how to calculate the offsets.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Mostly you have linear transforms which have no offsets. To locate positions in the transformed coordinate system, can't you use the nice grid you already have?

Comment: @luserdroog The grid is created by just using tiles that aren't transformed, and so you can use a nice equation to find the location.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the offsets in the affine transform (300, 100 here) *bypass* the scaling/skewing part. Remember, `x'=ax+by+e`, `y'=cx+dy+f`. So, `e` and `f` aren't scaled.

Comment: @luserdroog Oh man, for some reason, that never crossed my mind. So, I used (pX + 300, pY + 100) as the offset and then drew the image/diamond at (0, 0) and it worked fine. If you put that in an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An affine transformation matrix ([a b c d e f]) expresses the two equations

```
x' = ax + cy + e
y' = bx + dy + f
```

So, you can use the offsets *e* and *f* to bypass the scaling and skewing parts (the 4x4 linear transform embedded in the 2x3 or 3x3 matrix).

This is used a lot in postscript programming, where the coordinates used for drawing an object are relative to a *local* origin. If you're concatenating matrices, do the translation *before* scaling and skewing and the *e* and *f* values will remain unmolested.

Comment: I have to wait 9 hours before I give you your bounty :(

Comment: The equations should be `x' = ax + cy + e` and `y' = bx + dy + f`, since the the matrix is 
| a c e |
| b d f |
| 0 0 1 |