# How to generate a mathematical transform in JS given 4 initial points and 4 final points

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, transform

I am trying to figure out how to generate the transform necessary to take a set of coordinates for a rectangle-like polygon, given source and destination.

I am doing it in node using and I'm comfortable using the image manipulation libraries, I just can't find out the maths behind generating a transform with the information that I have.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867878/affine-transformation-matrix-offset

Comment: Not entirely tbh, I'm looking for a general answer as I do not know the angle of rotation necessarily. I just have a starting set of coords and a final set of coords. There is a shift in perspective as it is not just rotation and translation and might involve a skew as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have source coordinates and destination coordinates after applying of perspective transformation matrix. That matrix contains 8 independent coefficients. Source and destination points form 8 pairs of corresponding coordinates (`x1`<sub>(src)</sub>`=>x1`'<sub>(dst)</sub> and so on).

[This article](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2008_fall/Papers/proj.pdf) of Paul Heckbert shows theory - how to build system of eight linear equations to calculate coefficients of perspective transformation matrix.

Antigrain [library](http://www.antigrain.com/agg-2.5.zip) contains C++ implementation of this problem solution (in the file `agg_trans_perspective.h`). I'm sure that appropriate JS implementation does exist in the world.

After solving of eq. system you have coefficients `A..H` and can find transformation of any needed point  `(x,y)=>(x',y')`:

```
x' = (A * x + B * y + C) / (G * x + H * y + 1.0)
y' = (D * x + E * y + F) / (G * x + H * y + 1.0)
```